# Exporting all emails from Gmail with Java Mail API

Tags: java, email, gmail

So i am trying to write a program that will grab all my emails from my email adress and save them to a text file, the problem i am having is grabbing more then 1 email with the Java Mail API.

This is what i use to get an email which works fine, but i want to get every email in my inbox:

```
    public static void checkMail(String username, String password) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, password);
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
        Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
        for (Address address : in) {
            System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
        }
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
        System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If someone could possibly show me how to do this or explain it then that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all mails in folder inbox do this:

```
public static void checkMail(String username, String password) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, password);
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();

        for (Message msg : msgs) {
            try {
                Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
                for (Address address : in) {
                    System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
                }
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
                System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
                System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
                System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // close folder and store (normally in a finally block)
        inbox.close(false);
        store.close();

    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you want mails from other folders to you have to do the same for all folders.
You get them with store.getDefaultFolder().list() (do this recursive for all folders because folders can have subfolders)

```
protected void recurseFolders(final Folder folder) {
    // folder can hold messages
    if ((folder.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0) {

        // process them

    }

    // folder can hold other folders
    if ((folder.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS) != 0) {
        for (final Folder subfolder : folder.list()) {

            // process them recursive
            recurseFolders(subfolder);

        }
    }

}
```

Look here: https://github.com/salyh/elasticsearch-river-imap